# is it possible to trim a video file in linux without creating a copy and while watching video file

Tags: linux, video-editing, mencoder

I realize this is a tall order and may not be possible yet.  I would like to be able to trim off the watched portion of the video file on long video files (such as the olympics) to save disk space.  I have been googling, but not finding anything that might help.  Everything that I am seeing requires a copy of the video file to be created. Is there any way to trim a video file on the fly while watching it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in general, for any PC: Writing to a file (at least, shifting all the bytes on disk), and reading to it just won't work, unless I am mistaken.

You would need a single program to handle all the OS requirements behind the scenes. And it would probably involve an in-memory copy for viewing, and on-disk for editing.